# Node.js fetching Twitter Streaming API - EADDRNOTAVAIL

Tags: node.js, authentication, twitter

I have the following code written in node.js to access to the Twitter Streaming API. If I `curl` the URL below, it works. However, I cannot get it to work with my code.

```
var https = require('https');

https.request('https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json', function(res) {
  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    var d = JSON.parse(chunk);
    console.log(d);
  });
});
```

But I receive the following

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: connect EADDRNOTAVAIL
    at errnoException (net.js:642:11)
    at connect (net.js:525:18)
    at Socket.connect (net.js:589:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (net.js:77:12)
    at new ClientRequest (http.js:1073:25)
    at Object.request (https.js:80:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jordan/Projects/twitter-stream/app.js:3:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
```

If anyone can offer an alternative solution, or explain to me why this doesn't work, I would be very grateful.

Comment: You need to change the port, it's not available... :)

Comment: @AmirAbuShareb but curl had no problems with the default port? I guess I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: could i see line `10` in `app.js` ?

Comment: @AmirAbuShareb my apologies, the error log corresponded to an old version of the script. I have updated my original post, which now points to line 3. All of the code is there.

Comment: could you listen on `error` event that the `request` can emit, see if any errors are emitted prior to this error... `req.on('error', function () { console.dir(arguments); });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently faced the same problem .Here's the soln

```
 var https = require('https');   
 var options = {   
   host : 'stream.twitter.com',   
   path : '/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=bob',    
   method : 'GET',  
   headers : {   
   "Authorization": "Basic "+new Buffer("userName:passwd").toString("base64")
  }   
 };
 var request = https.request(options,function(response){   
   var body = '';
   response.on("data",function(chunk){    
    var tweet = JSON.parse(chunk);  
    console.log(tweet.text);  
  });  
 });  
 request.end();
```

Comment: This worked :) Thank you. Will any tweets be missed with this method? I feel like trying to parse a chunk may not always be a valid JSON document.

Comment: One cannot wait for response to end to parse data because its a streaming api and since every chunk received is valid json .So i think it won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

`https.request()` wants an options object as its first argument, not a string URL. However, you're probably better off using mikeal's request library, which does take string URLs.

Answer (score 0):

1) as ebohlman already stated https.request takes an options object as first parameter.

```
http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback
```

2) your JSON.parse will most likely fail because the "data" event will be emitted on every chunk and the response could span over more chunks, therefore wait until the response has ended.

```
var data = ""
res.on('data',function(chunk){
   data+=chunk
})
res.on('end',function(){
  try  {
     var parsed = JSON.parse(data)
  } catch(e) {
     console.log('failed to parse...',e)
  }
})
```

Comment: The point is that it's a streaming API. I believe the chunks are placed appropriate so that I can parse each one.

Answer (score 0):

jst try killing the process node through `killall node` or do `ps -aux|grep node` and kill the process through its ID.It will work then.Yeah if you are running on linux.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, the issue was that I am using an older version of Nodejs (v0.6.19), in that version [http.get](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.19/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) requires the first parameter as an options object with at least host and path attributes.  In the newer versions you can simply give the url string.

```
http.get({host:'www.google.com',path:'/index.html'}, function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```